# UncaughtExceptionHandler not called

Tags: java, groovy, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am having trouble using the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in Groovy/Java.

```
class UncaughtExceptionLogger implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        //TODO do some logging;
        println "test";
    }
```

main..groovy

```
def main(){
    def handler = new UncaughtExceptionLogger();
    Thread.defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = handler
    String s; 
    s.charAt(10); // causes a NullPointerException but the exception handler is not called 
}

main();
```

Why I expect is the exception handler to be called when the `NullPointerException` is thrown, however this does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have to spawn it with separate thread:

```
class UncaughtExceptionLogger implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        //TODO do some logging;
        println "test";
    }
}

def main(){
    Thread.defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionLogger()
    String s;
    s.charAt(10); // causes a NullPointerException but the exception handler is not called
}

Thread.start {
  main()
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? Isn't Groovy running in a Thread?